# Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop drops into initramfs after PXE boot with no errors

Tags: 14.04, initramfs, pxe

I've been experimenting with PXE booting so that if any of the systems on my home network crash I can rescue boot them into an OS off my Home Server.

As a test i'm trying to PXE Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop to the PC I use all the time.

- PC Specs: HP Pavilion p6623w (Modified) (Upgraded RAM, GPU, PSU, +1 HDD) Windows 7 Home Prem installed on HDD0
- The PXE Server Specs: HP Pavilion SLIM s5704y (No modifications) Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 10130 installed on the HDD. PXE Software: Serva 2.1

(Honestly, none of that probably matters, but still providing)

(The above was copied and pasted from a different question I solved myself, however this information is still pertinent to my current question.)

Now, the issue I am having is that without any errors or provided reason, Ubuntu drops into Busy box at initramfs prompt.

This would be no issue... if i was savvy with Linux. I'm fairly new to command line in any OS, so i'm not entirely sure what string i need to throw in the command prompt to continue to the regular installation.

This is the boot script provided by Serva's website that i'm using: (I did slightly modify it to fit my situation)

```
[PXESERVA_MENU_ENTRY]
asset    = Ubuntu LTS 14.04 Desktop Live
platform = amd64
kernel   = /NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/casper/vmlinuz
append   = showmounts toram root=/dev/cifs initrd=/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/casper/initrd.lz,/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/casper/INITRD_N11.GZ boot=casper netboot=cifs nfsroot=//$IP_BSRV$/NWA_PXE_SHARE/$HEAD_DIR$ NFSOPTS=-o user=serva,pass=avres,ro ip=dhcp ro
```

Additionally the ISO i'm using is brand new straight from Ubuntu's website. So I won't be surprised if someone here blames this on drivers, specially since NIC drivers are what's keeping my Windows 10 and Windows Server 2008 ISO's from booting properly. All of these ISOs are brand new.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possibly related to this unresolved issue https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/668429